# GDC 2011 - San Fran

Tags: gdc

Anyone out here right now? It would be great to meet up with some of you all and talk shop! Ill be around the expo the whole time. Send me an email or linkedin message!

ccc@c3sound.com
http://www.linkedin.com/in/c3sound

Answer (score 1):

I would have loved to have gone, but its too expensive for me at the moment :(

The Game audio podcast did a great round up of the most interesting events - http://www.gameaudiopodcast.com/?m=201103

Answer (score 1):

Join the Pyramind network and get access to tons of GDC Audio Videos

Answer (score 0):

Damn...missed this.  I was there all week. :(